# Calculating the stock loss in python3.7

Tags: python

A finance company is carrying out a study on the worst stock investments and would like to acquire a program to do so. The program must be able to analyze a chronological series of stock values in order to show the largest loss that it is possible to make by buying a share at a given time t0 and by selling it at a later date t1. The loss will be expressed as the difference in value between t0 and t1. If there is no loss, the loss will be worth 0.

- ***Input***
- **Line 1**: the number n of stock values available.
- **Line 2**: the stock values arranged in order, from the date of their introduction on the stock market v1 until the last known value 
  vn. The values are integers.
- ***Output***
- The maximal loss p, expressed negatively if there is a loss,
  otherwise 0.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMpK1.png)

（I'm new for programming, I only learned the very simple basics of python.it's hard for me. I have no idea about this problem. I need some ideas.thank you.)

Comment: Please post the code you've tried so far and the problems encountered and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: How did they get -3 at the end? I don't get it. It seems an easy problem, if I know what to code.

Comment: @SamuelGiftson because the largest decrease in value is from 4 at t3 to 1 at t5, so -3 is the corresponding loss

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is to calculate the Maximum Drawdown. There are packages for that purpose but a very basic approach would be to use a simple `for` loop and check the max drawdown at each point:

```
Line_2 = [3,2,4,2,1,5]

x_high = Line_2[0]
x_low = Line_2[0]
max_loss = 0
for x in Line_2:
    if x > x_high:
        x_high = x
        x_low = x
    elif x < x_low:
        x_low = x
    loss = x_low-x_high
    if loss < max_loss:
        max_loss = loss
print(max_loss)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Quastiat seems to have a simpler version than me. But if you want to use alternate method. Here it is

```
number_of_stock=int(input("Number of stock prices: "))
stock_values=[]
x=0
high_value=0

#This loop gets all the input,and highest value at the same time
#that is not at the end of list and store the index of the highest value in t.
while(x<number_of_stock):
    stock_values.append(int(input("Please input stock value: ")))
    if(high_value<stock_values[x] and (x!=number_of_stock-1)):
        high_value=stock_values[x]
        t=x
    x=x+1
x=t
#I am just reusing the variable x, since I used that to keep 
#the while loop to keep looping in the previous loop (which is not always good)
#I stored it in x so I can only loop from that value to the end.
#At the same time I am finding the highest difference which is
#maximal loss
maximum_loss=0
while(x<len(stock_values)):
    if(x!=len(stock_values)-1): x=x+1
    else: break
    loss=stock_values[t]-stock_values[x]
    if(maximum_loss<loss): maximum_loss=loss
print("Maximal loss: -"+str(maximum_loss))
```